# Polynomial Complex Partial Fraction Question

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, partial-fractions

I'm trying to find the partial fraction decomposition of the complex function $$\frac{1}{z^3-2z^2+z-2}$$ but after decomposing and writing as $$A(z-i)(z+i)+B(z-2)(z+i)+C(z-2)(z-i)=1$$ I do not know how to proceed and find $A$, $B$ and $C$.

Comment: Proceed via your favorite method for partial fractions, like substituting in values for $z$.

Comment: If you evaluate at $z=i$ you get $B(i-2)(i+i)=1$. Therefore, $B=1/(2i(i-2))$. If you evaluate at $z=-i$ you get $C(-i-2)(-i-i)=1$. Therefore, $C=1/(2i(i+2))$. If you evaluate at $z=2$ you get $A(2-i)(2+i)=1$. Therefore, $A=1/(4+1)$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_cover-up_method

Comment: Thank you all for your responses and clearing my head.